# Thinkpad T15 clickpad button not working in linux

Tags: debian, touchpad, thinkpad

I am running Debian on a Lenovo Thinkpad T15. Everything on the touchpad and trackpad is working fine except the click button on the clickpad. It is not broken as I've booted up Windows and everything is working fine.

Info:

`user@NA:~$ synclient
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 46
RightEdge               = 1000
TopEdge                 = 42
BottomEdge              = 680
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 61
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 12
HorizScrollDelta        = 12
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 1
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 0.8
MaxSpeed                = 5
AccelFactor             = 0.4
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 2
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 6
VertHysteresis          = 6
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 581
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 637
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0`

user@NA:~$ uname -a
Linux NA 5.10.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1 (2021-04-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**xev** returns nothing when clicking the touchpad.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer which also solved another issue (problem with the touchpad after suspend).

Add the following to /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet **psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0**"

then sudo update-grub